# How to access highlighted text with pbcopy?

Tags: macos, shell-script, zsh, highlighting

How can I "catch" text that has been selected (highlighted) via shell script? It was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860634/8315879) to use `pbcopy`. The script would be idle in the background and when a certain key combination is pressed it "catches" the text the user has highlighted and stores it in a variable.

I first set up a shortcut to be `/home/ben/bin/catch.sh`
But I don't know how to write the script ...

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

pbcopy $0
```

Comment: Are Cmd+C and Cmd+V not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: They are but I want to write functions that manipulate the captured words. Similar to 3-finger tap on a highlighted word on macOS searches it in a dictionary. I'm planning to feed it into a script that writes the word to an Excel file.

Comment: Maybe `pbcopy` is the wrong way to go. I just want to capture highlighted text somehow. I thought shell script was the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To capture it, don't you want `pbpaste` rather than `pbcopy`:

```
var=$(pbpaste)
```

Depending on your choice of terminal programme and setup, merely selecting the text may not copy it to the clipboard.

If you're referring to zsh's idea of a selection - the region in emacs mode or visual selection in vi mode then you need to write a zle widget and use `$MARK` and `$CURSOR` as indexes into `$BUFFER`.